# Pattern rules behave differently in GNU Make and BSD Make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, freebsd, bsdmake

I have a single Makefile.
On a FreeBSD machine with both **gmake** and **make** installed, I run the same Makefile using both tools.
The output log for **make** and **gmake** is not the same. Why is this? And how can I "fix" this?

The logs are below:

$ gmake

```
compile main.cpp
linking myout
```

$ make

```
c++  -O2 -pipe -c main.cpp -o main.o
linking myout
```

$ cat Makefile

```
TARGET = myout

default: $(TARGET)

SRCS = main.cpp

OBJS = $(SRCS:%.cpp=%.o)

default: $(BIN)

%.o: %.cpp
    @echo compile $<
    @$(CXX) -c $< -o $@

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    @echo linking $@

    @$(CXX) $(OBJS) -o $@

clean:
    @rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your post does not include a question. Can you clarify what exactly you are asking?

Comment: I want gnu make with bsd make to output the same.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [FreeBSD make documentation](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?make(1)), it doesn't support pattern rules.  So your rule here:

```
%.o: %.cpp
        @echo compile $<
        @$(CXX) -c $< -o $@
```

in FreeBSD make is just an explicit rule telling make how to build the literal file `%.o` from the literal file `%.cpp`.  Since you don't try to build a file named `%.o` (you're trying to build `main.o`), this rule is ignored / never used.

It looks like if you want something that will work the same way between both versions of make you'll have to restrict yourself to the POSIX standard suffix rules format, like this:

```
.SUFFIXES: .cpp .o
.cpp.o:
        @echo compile $<
        @$(CXX) -c $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 0):

The default build utilities are different. FreeBSD uses a different implementation of make than GNU/Linux. The respective man pages outline differences.

https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/difference-gmake-gnu-and-freebsd-make.28784/

Comment: I don't understand why some people downvote this, because it is right to say that FreeBSD make is not the same as Gnu Make aka gmake;  eg FreeBSD make has a ability to generate targets on the fly (a kind of "meta-make" like with gmake's .SECONDEXPANSION), something very difficult to do with gmake, it has a better introspection engine, and at some point a better performance. Of course, this is not the answer to the question, but what was the question hu ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Your statement is correct, however it does not help the person(s) asking question find a solution. The best approach is to come up with a solution that caters the specific question.

Comment: My answer explains why the log output is different and points to the man page that explains. What solution could there be to a question that asks why the logs are different?   If you want the logs to be the same, use the same tool.